# Awk Command - combine two commands

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, iftop

Slowly muddling my way through learning how to manipulate variables for a bash script I'm writing. I'm trying to use AWK (tried Grep but not granular enough I don't think) to pull the source and dest from iftop.

The base iftop command I'm using is:

```
sudo iftop -t -L1 -s1 -f "dst host 10.0.0"
```

I can switch the dst to src to get the reverse. So the sample output from the command above is:

```
interface: eth0
IP address is: 10.0.0.104
MAC address is: b8:27:eb:6a:26:84
Listening on eth0
   # Host name (port/service if enabled)            last 2s   last 10s  last 40s cumulative
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 10.0.0.255                               =>         0b         0b         0b         0B
     10.0.0.15                                <=     1.14Kb     1.14Kb     1.14Kb       291B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total send rate:                                       480b       480b       480b
Total receive rate:                                  1.29Kb     1.29Kb     1.29Kb
Total send and receive rate:                         1.76Kb     1.76Kb     1.76Kb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Peak rate (sent/received/total):                       480b     1.29Kb     1.76Kb
Cumulative (sent/received/total):                      120B       331B       451B
============================================================================================
```

I'm trying to use AWK to output the two IP addresses (or could be domains) to variables I can then do something with in bash.

If I use a command such as:

```
 sudo iftop -t -L1 -s1 -f "dst host 10.0.0" 2> /dev/null | awk '/^   1 / {print $2}'
```

That gives me the first IP or domain, but I now need the 2nd line down. I tried using something like:

```
 sudo iftop -t -L1 -s1 -f "dst host 10.0.0" 2> /dev/null | awk '/^   1 /{c=2} c&&c-- {print $2}'
```

This almost works, but because of the white spacing on the 2nd line, AWK counts what is column 2 in the first line as column 1 in the second, so the output I get is:

```
10.0.0.255
<=
```

I feel like I'm close but I can't work out how to use a single AWK command to spit out the right two numbers.

I can't easily run a second pattern compare for the 2nd number as the white space before the IP or domain isn't enough to go on I don't think, so ideally I want to match on the first, then move to the next line but choose column 1 rather than column 2.

I also want to avoid running a second iftop command as the results may be different to the first.

I then need to know how to convert those to variables for a bash script rather than print them to screen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 ... | awk '$1 == "1" {print $2 ; l=NR+1 ; } NR == l { print $1 ;}'
```

where

- `$1 == "1"`  select line where first field is 1
- `{print $2`  print it's value
- `l=NR+1 ; }` remember next line
- `NR == l` select second line
- `{ print $1 ;}` print first field

remember awk doesn't think in term of column, just field.

thoses two lines are equivalent using `$1` `$2`

```
 hello world
       hello              world
```

### Assigning to var

```
... | awk '$1 == "1" {printf "A=%s\n",$2 ; l=NR+1 ; } NR == l { printf "B=%s\n",$1 ;}' > /tmp/.var
. /tmp/.var
```

last line is a dot (`.`) a space () and `/tmp/.var`

- printf in awk need a comma after argument.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you - how would I go about assigning the two outputs to seperate variables?

Comment: Thanks for the var assignment, if I run the above command I get the following error: awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf("A=%s13.107.4.50")? - I think I'm doing something wrong with that last line?

Comment: I ended up writing this to an array which did the job, I'll mark this as the answer though and edit my final solution in the main comment

Comment: - printf in awk need a comma after argument. (i fixed in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
sudo iftop -t -L1 -s1 -f "dst host 10.0.0" | grep -E '=>|<=' | cut -c 5- | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

which returns:

```
10.0.0.255
10.0.0.15
```

The problem is that the number of "columns" is not the same on the following two lines. In the command above `cut` is used to delete the first 5 characters, thus it deletes the "1".

```
 1 10.0.0.255                         =>         0b         0b         0b         0B
   10.0.0.15                          <=     1.14Kb     1.14Kb     1.14Kb       291B
```

Answer (score 0):

With `grep`:

```
... | grep -oP '^\s+\d* \K(\d+\.){3}\d+'
10.0.0.255
10.0.0.15
```